# How to set padding for selection tab in TabLayout on Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In my application I should `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`.
I want when selected Item set padding for `tabIndicatorColor` in `tabLayout`.

By default show me such as this image : 
[image: Image 1]

Bu t I want when selected item, show me such as this : 
[image]

I want set Padding for `tabIndicatorColor`.

**My TabLayout XML code:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/serialDetail_tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/allCapsTabLayout"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />
```

How can I it? please help me. Thanks all <3

Comment: can you send me custom tablayout for solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked second option. It is more easier.

Comment: @SibinDavis, do you know how can I set padding for this library : https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout ?

Comment: @SibinDavis your second option solve my problem and this is awesome trick :D

Comment: @SibinDavis, send your answer to other post for accept it

Comment: its simple add android:paddingBottom="your dimension in dp" to TabLayout
No need of any library.

Comment: @RamPrakashBhat, thanks my friend

Comment: @Jong did you tried my solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do this. Either you use a custom layout for tab or just add a view below the tab of same color.The second option is more easier.

Comment: **I think there is no default option for this** you are wrong there is option available

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible without custom view and external library..

you may create one selector file

**tab_indicator_line.xml**  add into drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="2dp"/>

                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="2dp"/>

                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Now apply in tabLayout using

```
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_line"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
```

Tell me if any query..